# Redux state access from actions, should i make store global?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am quite new to redux, here is a simplified version of my db:

```
store: {
  userID: 1234,
  userData: { // fetch-ed from api
    foo,
    bar,
    ...
}
```

On the change of userID, I want to fetch userData, I found a library for called redux-thunk, which can make dispatch-es async (I am fetching the data), but for the fetch URL I need the userID from the store, and I don't know how to access it directly from an action.

Should I pass it to the action every time i call it like
`dispatch(updateUser(store.getState().userID))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it looks to me like you're on the right track, but might want to rethink how your store is structured. If you have the code where you define your reducers, it'd be helpful to see that here, as well as somewhere where you use `connect` to access this data in a component's props.

Absent that, here are my suggestions.

It sounds like you're looking for functionality somewhere along the lines of being able to display user profiles, switching between them. In that case, I'd suggest that you structure your store with a list of users, rather than a single user object that gets overwritten. It'd look something like this:

```
{ 
  users: [{ id: '123', name: 'Hello' }, { id: '234', name: 'Goodbye' }],
  currentUserId: '123'
}
```

In this context, to switch the user you're showing on a particular page, (or who you're signed in as), you'd simply change which user you *select* in the component, rather than updating the store to overwrite `user` with the new user. In a case where a UI element updates the current user without updating the URL (ie, something calls `dispatch(updateCurrentUserId('234'))`, then your component should just select the user from the `users` key in the store based on that:

```
const MyComponent = ({ user }) => (
  <div>User name is { user.name }</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ users, currentUserId ) => ({
  user: users.find(u => u.id === currentUserId)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

That way, to switch which user was represented, you'd just need to change the `currentUserId` in the store.

That assumes that you've already fetched the list of users from the API. If you are fetching them one at a time, you could indeed use redux thunk. I'd still suggest storing users as a list, so you could easily toggle between them. In that case, your thunk would want to grab the user from the store if it existed, or fetch it if it didn't. Something like this:

```
// Alternately, you could pass *no* argument, and grab currentUserId
// from state like users below
const getUser = userId => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const localUsers = getState().users;
  const localUser = localUsers.find(u => u.id === userId);

  if (localUser) {
    // Because the user is in the store, we just need to point the frontend
    // to the right user.
    dispatch(updateCurrentUserId(userId));

  } else {
    // Fetch the user, add them to the store, and then point to them.
    fetch(`whatever.com/users/${userId}`)
      .then(response => {
         dispatch(addUser(response.data));
         dispatch(updateCurrentUserId(userId));
      }).catch(err => /* do something */);
  }
}
```

This thunk allows you to behave conditionally and asynchronously on the basis of whether or not your user exists in the data. Unlike your design, however, you're not overwriting the current user as a new one arrives.

Note you could also do this without `currentUserId`, instead just parsing the user ID from the URL, for example.